# When Fire meets Water

Tags: thermodynamics

To preface, I am not a scientific mind, but a writer looking for some validity to a possible scene. That being said, please forgive me!

In my scene, huge masses of fire are raining from the sky and crashing into a salt-water ocean.

[Edit]: I would imagine the buring substance as some sort of 'napalm'? I am unfamiliar with how fire would exist in the atmosphere. I guess that's the magic part (;

My question is:

What would happen when fire meets water in such a way? Would it make noise? Would it cause large amounts of steam? How about smoke? If it occurred near land, would the steam or smoke drift away or towards the land?

I realize I am asking about the results of interactions between something magical and the physical world, but please bear with me!

Comment: What is on fire?

Comment: Like this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FA7uUEx1t0w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It matters what's on fire.

- If it's a flammable material that floats, like oil or gasoline, some fraction of it will remain on or return to the surface and you may have flames on the water. (This is basically the only thing that I remember from watching *Black Beauty* as a kid.)
- If it's a flammable material that sinks, the water will probably extinguish the flames, but the residual heat may boil the water around the fuel and send up clouds of steam.
- If it's a flammable material that reacts with water, like metallic [sodium](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sodium+in+water+video) or [lithium](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lithium+in+water+video), it may burn *more* violently when it hits the water.